# Windows Vista 32 bit doesn't boot in Normal Mode. Only boots in Safe mode

Tags: boot, windows-vista, normal-mode

I own a laptop that has Windows Vista 32 bit installed in it. I have been unable to switch it on in normal mode for a day now. When I try to switch it on in the said mode, Microsoft Corporation is displayed on the screen and the bars move from left to right this is how it looks [image]and this continues for as long as I allow it to, without making any progress. I have allowed the laptop to stay in this state for a max of 10 minutes yet, before manually shutting it down via the power button. Next when I try to switch it on, I am prompted with the options of various modes to switch it on in and I am able to successfully switch it on in Safe Mode. I can't figure what's impeding it from switching on in Normal Mode.

Comment: Have you tried using the System File Checker tool in safe mode to repair missing or corrupted system files? Might help

Comment: +1 for System File Checking suggestion. Run > sfc /scannow in safe mode. It often takes a while, but I've seen it work wonders. Alternatively, have you added any hardware to the system recently enough that there could be a correlation?

Comment: This seems to have fixed the issue for now. @Catatonic27 I had recently uninstalled Microsoft Visual Studio and some other programs. Maybe that's the cause!

Comment: @Malcolm Please post your solution as an answer so that I may accept it :)

Comment: @Ritesh Bhakre, glad I could help